# Ruby on Rails - Sunspot Solr search configuration

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, configuration, solr, sunspot

I configured a Sunspot/Solr in my Ruby on Rails project and it's working fine.
Thus, it's response time is great, it's finding records quickly.

But I've two questions/problems which I can't find resolve and I cannot find any information or explanation about.

a) I want to know how to change the engine behavior, e.g. when I search "windows" I can find all records containing that word. But if I search "window" no record is returned. Are there any way to change any parameter to change this behavior?

b) I want to know if I implement some file uploading script or utility, I would be able to index those related files, I mean, if I upload a PDF attached to a record (using ActiveRecord). Will Solr/Sunspot able to index and find it.

Regards.

Comment: You will want to update the schema to handle (a). As far as (b), that is a great question. I'm interested to know this as well.

Comment: Please add your schema.xml and model definition here

Answer (score 0):

I can provide answers from Solr perpective, check if you can map it into Sunspot apis :-

1. For windows and window search, you would need to enable [stemming](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/AnalyzersTokenizersTokenFilters#Stemming) on your field. Stemming would reduce the words to their roots and would allow you to match the results to the root word always. 
   Check how you can add filters to your fields defined in Sunspot OR you can define a text field in schema.xml with stemming filter configured.
2. Solr [Extract Handler](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/ExtractingRequestHandler) provides ability to consume a rich document and parse the contents. Solr used apache Tika underlying and can parse most of the rich documents format. Just check for a matching api for it in Sunspot. I know Solrj provides an easy api for this.